# How does range partitioner handle parent partitions across executors?

Tags: apache-spark, shuffle, partitioner

In Apache Spark, partitioners are used to define how data is going to be shuffled. They all have a `getPartition(key: Any): Int` method to do this.

In particular in `RangePartitioner`, developers need to transfer information about the `RDD` to start it. So I am confused about where do partitioners actually perform their work: the executors, the driver or the master?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by *"developers need to transfer information about the RDD to start it"*?

Comment: ```class RangePartitioner[K : Ordering : ClassTag, V](partitions: Int,rdd: RDD[_ <: Product2[K, V]],private var ascending: Boolean = true) extends Partitioner``` this code is the definition of the range partitioner, the second parameter is rdd info.